# bundler rails com problema de usuario

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ola, eu tenho uma gota na digitalocean, e instalei o ruby on rails atravez do painel principal, nao consigo usar o bundler atravez do upstart ou cron , ele diz que o usuario nao possui o bundler, porem quando acesso via ssh consigo fazer tudo normalmente.
ex: bundle exec....

nao sei oq esta acontecento, tentei rodar

sudo -su root bundle exec .....

ou

sudo -su rails bundle exec .....

mas nao da,  como eu faco pra executa o bundler com as mesmas caracteristicas q eu uso via ssh?

Comment: Você executa o bundler via ssh com o usuário sudo?

Comment: Que error que aparece?

Comment: Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: so que o user é o user corrente do ustart sabe... num sei muito bem como lida com isso

Comment: Analisando de fora eu pensaria que algo relacionado com ENV do usuário que você está usando na sua application tipo `/home/rails` e parece que o sudo não está carregando a ENV deste usuário. Tais usando RVM ou RBENV?